# Append extra get variable to URL via .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

I am trying to append an extra `get` variable onto a URL. I'm currently using OpenCart with a custom theme I bought. However, the developers of the theme have been unresponsive.

When I search for a product, it only searches the title. There is a checkbox to search the descriptions, but this is set to "off" by default, and I cannot find anywhere in the code to append or change this to the URL. It's a matter of adding `&description=true` to the end of the URL.

I have:

```
index.php?route=product/search&search=123
```

...and I need to append the description to this, to make it look like:

```
index.php?route=product/search&search=123&description=true
```

My last resort is to modify the .htaccess, so I can hijack the search request, per say, and amend this to the end.

I have tried writing some, but to no avail.

```
RewriteRule ^/page /page?var=val [QSA]
```

I just cannot seem to fiqure out how I need to write this, in order for it to work. Could some one please point me in the right direction?

**EDIT** - Still messing round and now I have:

```
RewriteRule index.php?route=product/search&search=(.*)  /index.php?route=product/search&search=$1&description=true [QSA]
```

It won't append it to the original, but when I add `&description=true` manually, it adds another one? So it becomes:

```
index.php?route=product/search&search=123&description=true&description=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule`. Use `RewriteCond` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/search&search=[^&]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /$0?description=true [QSA,L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` checks your query string. In the target we are using new parameter `description=true` with `QSA` that appends existing query string.

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: i havent a clue what it means but it works thank you, could you please elaborate on what it does and how it works if you don't mind.

Comment: I've added some explanation with reference links.

Comment: Hellow. I want to achieve almost same. but not working . Can you answer my question here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/386684/append-a-parametter-at-first-or-last-to-a-certain-url

Comment: That question belongs to SO since it is not Wordpress problem but a generic rewrite issue